What is the best practice for implementing AWS WAF for multiple (cloudfront + api_gateway)?
I am new with AWS Cloud and right now I'm working with AWS WAF and I have a multiple site/server (obviously with their respective github repository), I'm planning to implement a WAF for each site, but I'm not sure about its cots impact or whether it is a good practice.
This is my initial plan:
WAF_1 => cloudfront_1 and api_gateway_1
WAF_2 => cloudfront_2 and api_gateway_2
Let me know you opinion, this will be a great help. Thank you.
I'm expecting an opinion from someone who is espert to this field
